# It's possible to register already defined enum for MOC?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

For instance I have enum from thirdparty library:

```
namespace Lib {
  enum class Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz
  };
};
```

I have tried use next wrapper

```
namespace Qml {
    Q_NAMESPACE
    using Foo = Lib::Foo;
    Q_ENUMS(Foo)
}
```

with `qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject`, but its don't work for me.

Can I register one in `Meta Object System` for using in `QML`, but without duplicates like:

```
class QmlObject {
    Q_GADGET

public:
    enum Foo {
        Bar = Lib::Bar,
        Baz = Lib::Baz
    };
    Q_ENUM(Foo)
};
```

Version of `Qt` is `5.15.2`. Thanks.

Comment: According to https://www.kdab.com/new-qt-5-8-meta-object-support-namespaces/ you should use Q_ENUM_NS and you can change `Qml` in `Lib` in your wrapper code and skip the `using`, but with that I cannot make it work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution using the library [magic_enum](https://github.com/egorodet/MagicEnum) (at least v0.8.1, see [limitations](https://github.com/egorodet/MagicEnum/blob/master/doc/limitations.md)) and bit of modification in implementation of [qmlRegisterType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType):

```
#include <QtQml/qqmlprivate.h>
#include <QtCore/private/qmetaobjectbuilder_p.h>
#include <magic_enum.hpp>
    
template<class T, class ... En>
int qmlRegisterTypeWithEnums(const char *uri, int versionMajor, int versionMinor, const char *qmlName)
{
    QML_GETTYPENAMES

    //! register our enums here
    QMetaObjectBuilder builder(&T::staticMetaObject);

    ([](QMetaObjectBuilder & builder)
    {
        QMetaEnumBuilder enumBuilder {
            builder.addEnumerator(QByteArray::fromStdString(std::string{magic_enum::enum_type_name<En>()}))
        };
        enumBuilder.setIsScoped(magic_enum::is_scoped_enum_v<En>);
        constexpr auto entries = magic_enum::enum_entries<En>();
        for (const auto & pair : entries) {
            enumBuilder.addKey(QByteArray::fromStdString(std::string{pair.second}), static_cast<int>(pair.first));
        }
    }(builder), ...);
    //! ***************************

    QQmlPrivate::RegisterType type = {
        0,

        qRegisterNormalizedMetaType<T *>(pointerName.constData()),
        qRegisterNormalizedMetaType<QQmlListProperty<T> >(listName.constData()),
        sizeof(T), QQmlPrivate::createInto<T>,
        QString(),

        uri, versionMajor, versionMinor, qmlName, builder.toMetaObject(),

        QQmlPrivate::attachedPropertiesFunc<T>(),
        QQmlPrivate::attachedPropertiesMetaObject<T>(),

        QQmlPrivate::StaticCastSelector<T,QQmlParserStatus>::cast(),
        QQmlPrivate::StaticCastSelector<T,QQmlPropertyValueSource>::cast(),
        QQmlPrivate::StaticCastSelector<T,QQmlPropertyValueInterceptor>::cast(),

        nullptr, nullptr,

        nullptr,
        0
    };

    return QQmlPrivate::qmlregister(QQmlPrivate::TypeRegistration, &type);
}
```

Now for thirdparty enum

```
namespace Lib {
  enum class Foo {
    Bar = 2,
    Baz = 4
  };
};
```

and target Qt class

```
namespace SomeQml {

    class QmlItem : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
        using Foo = Lib::Foo; // its important use without namespace in declaration
    
        Q_PROPERTY(Foo prop MEMBER m_val NOTIFY propChanged)
        ...
        Q_INVOKABLE handleFoo(Foo v);
        ...
    };

}
```

just call and use on QML side as `QmlItem.Bar` or `QmlItem.Baz` as an integer :

```
qmlRegisterTypeWithEnums<QmlItem, Lib::Foo>("my.pack", 1, 0, "QmlItem");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a great answer, but you can declare your enum in a `QObject` and it will get registered when you register the `QObject`:

```cpp
#include <QObject>

class QmlObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QmlObject(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }

    enum Foo {
        Bar = Lib::Bar,
        Baz = Lib::Baz
    };
    Q_ENUMS(Foo)
};
```

```cpp
    qmlRegisterType<QmlObject>("MyApp", 1, 0, "QmlObject");
```

But to use the 3rd party library you need to use `static_cast` to move your enums from `QmlObject::Foo` to `Lib::Foo`, e.g.

```cpp
Lib::Foo libFoo = static_cast<Lib::Foo>(qmlFoo);
```

Comment: We do same now, but I want stop it. It's not answer.

Comment: Alternates to a QObject would be a non-creatable QObject, such as a singleton, or, perhaps, in a QGadget?

Comment: Use singleton wrapper for every separate enum sounds like overcosts.

Comment: You just put all your enums onto 1 singleton. Similar to the Qt singleton object. https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h

Comment: Im asking about enormous count thirdparty enums which may change. I don't want duplicate them.

Comment: That is an interesting problem. The solution could be not specific to what you do with moc, as that narrows the scope and may not actually be solvable. Hence your StackOverflow question is there a solution to that problem. But, more generically speaking, managing a possibly every changing set of enums from your supplier. Well, you could (1) interact with the supplier and request how they offer the enums so you can automate their mappings to Qt better, or (2) script the import yourself (e.g. python to scan the headers or a doc tool (such as qdoc) to reverse engineer it from comments).