# How to import the enums from a library(header file) and register them for qml

Tags: qt, enums, qml

I have a header file (library) containing only enums defined. I wanted to use these enums defined in this header file in our project.

Code Snippet of the Library class:

```
namespace d_types {

namespace wc_types {

enum BUTTON_TYPE {
    NONE,
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT      };

enum BUTTON_ACTION {
    PRESSED,
    CLICKED,
    DOUBLE_CLICKED,
    RELEASED
};
}
```

I dont want this file to be changed. But wanted these enums to be registered using Q_ENUMS or Q_ENUMS_NS to be accessed in QML. From the QEnum documentation I could see that the Enums should belongs to the same class. Since the library is just a file of enums, how do we inherit the enums into a class and register it.

Whats the best way to approach the imported library untouched and also wanted these enums to be accessed in qml?

Comment: I never had much luck Q_ENUM_NS, but technically you can add Q_ENUM_NS for the given namespaces/enums in a _different_ file

Comment: tried that approach, just included the header library file and tried accessing those enums and registering it . But it didnt work

Comment: Yeah, I think there is some bug with Q_ENUM_NS. Possibly this answer can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131348/its-possible-to-register-already-defined-enum-for-moc/74499417#74499417

Comment: If you look at the meta object compiler, e.g. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#indexOfEnumerator you see that enumerators can be accessed if they are connected to a QMetaObject, typically a QObject. So, unfortunately, in order to register your enums the need to be duplicated in a QObject. We've done this before and, it's painful, and we need to static_cast<> between the QML facing enum and the underlying enum. I don't think this is the answer you were looking for, but, it is the answer we use in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifndef ENUMTYPES_H    
#ifndef ENUMTYPES_H
#define ENUMTYPES_H
#include <QObject>

namespace enum_types {
Q_NAMESPACE

#include ".h" // include the header file where the enums are defined

Q_ENUM_NS(BUTTON_TYPE)
}; 

#endif // ENUMTYPES_H
```

We can achieve it by using Q_ENUM_NS and including the header file containing enums under the namespace